Handling Custom Exceptions in step functions for glue
I have a glue job in which I have created a custom exception named RetryableException and NonRetryableException. I want to retry only in case of RetryableException and DLQ for NonRetryableException. However according to the documentation, only pre defined errors like States.* and Lambda.* etc can be covered in retry block. Which means even the NonRetryableException will be retried if the glue job task fails. Is there any way to retry the glue job only when the RetryableException is thrown?

I wonder where you did get "only States.* errors can be covered in retry block" from? The doc also shows that errors from Lambda are "Lambda.(something)" as opposed to "States.*".

Yeah missed that part. However still remains for custom exceptions in glue

I am not familiar with Glue but I'd expect it to be: "Glue.NonRetryableException" for example.
